# Extending a TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript

I figured I could define an interface like so:

```
export interface IMessageContextWithAudience<T> extends T {
  audience: IAudienceMember[];
}
```

which would allow for interfaces to "inherit" another strongly typed property but sadly it is balking at the **extends T** part of the definition. Is there a way to achieve this goal another way?

---

another failed attempt:

```
export interface IMessageContextWithAudience<T, K extends keyof T> {
  [key: keyof T]: K;
  audience: IAudienceMember[];
}
```

> complains that `key`:  An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.

Comment: how about `type IMessageContextWithAudience<T> = T & {audience: IAudienceMember[]}`?  Does it need to be an `interface`?

Comment: I don't think it does actually, that should solve my problem